# laravel: insert views into array

Tags: php, view, laravel-4

I want show dynamic numbers of tickets (views) in my main view (show). I get an array of tickets data from the database. The problem is that `laravel` don't allow me echo view from view (maybe it possible? and somebody knows how make it) so I create array of tickets views in the controller and pass them to my main view (show). In the main view I use `foreach` to run over all the views and show them. for some reason `laravel` throws error `Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception`. it means that something wrong with my views. What am I doing wrong?

**My Controller Code:**

```
foreach( $tickets as $ticket ){

$oldTickets[] = View::make('helpers.eventBox', array( 'ticket' => $ticket ));
}

    $layout = View::make('layouts.main');
    $layout->nest('content','profile.show.show',array(

        'oldTickets' => $oldTickets,                
    ));

    return $layout;
```

**Show View:**

```
foreach( $oldTickets as $ticket ){ 

        echo $ticket;                                               
 }
```

When I pass single view from controller to the view it works. What can my problem be? What is the best solution for it?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I had bug in my view. generally it possible to render from view page. I fix my issue.

the blade solution looks like right way too, I try it but don't success, if I will see 5 'up points' near your answer I will mark it as a right question for other users that will have same issue.

sorry and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to render a particular view for each ticket, and all that nested in a main view.

So, in controller I would pass all `tickets` array to a view eg. like:

```
return View::make('tickets.list')->with('tickets', $tickets);
```

And then in view I would call blades `render each` function, which renders a partial view for all objects in passed array.

```
@each('tickets._item', $tickets, 'ticket')
```

As I've read, it is not documented, but here you can read about it: http://www.neontsunami.com/post/@each-in-laravel-blade

Haven't checked it, but it should work. I've used render each in blade in Laravel 3 and it worked fine.

**UPDATE:**
I've checked that it works. This is what I did:

1. In controller I passed $tickets to a view, like above
2. Created file .../views/tickets/list.blade.php and inserted there code:

   `<ul>
   @each('tickets._item', $tickets, 'ticket')
   </ul>`
3. Created file .../views/tickets/_item.blade.php and inserted code:

   `<li>
   {{ $ticket->id }}
   </li>`

And thats it, all is working fine - for each ticket theres a view rendered defined in _item.blade.php file.

Comment: I try use `code` echo @each('helpers.eventBox', $oldTickets, 'ticket'); `code` but I always get this error. Only variables can be passed by reference. any ideas?

Comment: Don't call it with php like: `<?php echo each(...); ?>` but JUST with blade, so in your code just put `@each('tickets._item', $tickets, 'ticket')` - remember to have all files prefixed with extension blade.php eg. your file with tickets view should be like: views/tickets/_item.blade.php